# Setting mock location in Android is innaccurate (only half the distance from the last location)

Tags: android, android-testing, android-location

For a UI test, I'm trying to set a mock location. My app is location aware. I'm trying to test that logic in the app.

The first location is set correctly. However, the second location is often inaccurate. Most of the time, the second location ends up being the midway point between the first and second location. When I repeat setting the second location, the actual device GPS location moves a little closer but still not to the actual second location.

Here is an excerpt from the log:

```
First call to set mock location works perfectly:
setMockLocation: Set location to: latitude: 34.001 longitude: -118.485
onLocationResult: Got new location
checkIfBuildingDiscovered: Called with latitude: 34.001 longitude: -118.485
```

Second call to set mock location falls short by half the distance:

```
moveNorth: Attempted distance: 300
moveNorth: Actual distance: 298.92993
moveNorth: new location: latitude: 34.00369494585236 longitude: -118.485
    setMockLocation: Set location to: latitude: 34.00369494585236 longitude: -118.485
Got new location
getMinDistanceFromCurrentBuildings: Current location: latitude: 34.0023474 longitude: -118.485
getMinDistanceFromCurrentBuildings: Distance from previous location: 149.45686
```

Here is how I set the mock location:

```
Location location = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
location.setLatitude(latitude);
location.setLongitude(longitude);
// Set other parameters to make the location complete.

locationManager.setTestProviderLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, location);
Log.i(LOG_TAG, "setMockLocation: Set location to: latitude: " + latitude
        + " longitude: " + longitude);
```

Here is how the mock location service is enabled:

```
locationManager.addTestProvider(
        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        true,
        true,
        true,
        Criteria.POWER_LOW,
        Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
locationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, true);
locationManager.setTestProviderStatus(
        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
        LocationProvider.AVAILABLE,
        null,
        System.currentTimeMillis());
```

My best guess is that the Android device somehow doesn't like jumps in location that are too large. It might assume a wrong reading. So it might try to average it with previous GPS readings to limit the possible error reading.

How can my android test set the location to a specific mock location and ensure that's the actual location?

PS: I notice a similar behavior when I try to manually set a location in the Android emulator. I'll enter a new GPS location and hit send. The map activity will update the location in the direction of my GPS coordinates. Each time I hit send, it'll move closer to it. Other times, I enter new GPS coordinates, hit send, and the map activity will update directly to it.